# Does FIX8 library provide timeout mechanism for connection attempt?

Tags: c++, connection, fix8

I have `FIX8::Session::start(...)` method in my C++ code, which blocks the program forever in case the endpoint is unavailable at the moment. Is there a built-in FIX8 way to set timeout on connection attemps? I want to move forward if connection is failed after, let's say, two seconds attempt.
PS: I set "wait" parameters of start() method to false, it's not the reason of blocking.

I tried to move implementation of `FIX8::Session::start(...)` method to a background std::thread, but it seems to be not the proper way to solve the issue, since thread will need to be detached and running forever in case of method's freezing.
That's  why I'm wondering if there's a native way to solve it.
Thank you.